# What strings for classical guitar you advise to beginer?

Tags: strings, classical-guitar

Recently, I found an old classical guitar(1989) in my cupboard and now I want to tune it up! But I need to change the strings.

1. Which parameter of tension is better for beginners?
2. Does the brand of strings matter?
3. What do the numbers in the description like 28-43, 29-46 mean?
4. Which strings will you recommend for an absolute beginer?

Comment: Welcome to Musical Practice & Performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Measure to find out whether your guitar is a full-sized guitar or a shorter-scale guitar. On a full-sized guitar, the length of the strings, from the bridge saddle to the nut, is 648mm.

For a beginner, if you have a full-scale guitar, just use a package of nylon classical guitar strings labeled "standard tension" or "normal tension". Any brand will do.

The numbers indicate the diameter of each string, in fractions of an English inch, or in millimeters. Some musicians prefer a particular diameter of string for each of the six string positions, so they want to know the exact specifications.

If you have a shorter-scale guitar, you may need to find a special set of strings (all of which will be thicker in diameter) designed to provide the proper tension and tuning for a short-scale instrument.

[image]